# Complex AND/OR in backend conditional

Tags: haproxy

I am attempting to use a backend under the following condition:

> It is the prod site being requested (i.e. there is mysite.com and beta.mysite.com)
>
> AND
>
> It's an api request
>
> OR
>
> It's an opt-in request

I have the following acls setup for each condition:

```
acl prod hdr_beg(host) -i mysite.com
acl url_api  path_beg /api/
acl url_opt-in  path_beg /opt-in/
```

I would now like to redirect to the prod-api-backend like so:

```
use_backend prod-api-backend if prod AND ( url_api OR url_opt-in )
```

However, I can't seem to figure out how I can write a condition like this without receiving a configuration error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no 'and' in haproxy logic, but if you expand the brackets and write it like this, you should be good:

```
use_backend prod-api-backend if prod url_opt-in or prod url_api
```

Comment: I thought `AND` and `&&` were allowed, it's just that they're implicit?  Thanks for the tip, expanding out the brackets makes perfect sense

Comment: Implicit - check out "parse_acl_cond" method in https://github.com/haproxy/haproxy/blob/v1.6.0/src/acl.c

Answer (score 1):

Conjunction ("and") operators are implicit when you specify multiple conditions. Meaning when you do:

```
acl foo ...
acl bar ...
use_backend ... if foo bar
```

The `use_backend` is performed if both `foo` and `bar` match. You can specify `||` or `or` in between `foo` and `bar` to make it a disjunction.

If you want a mixture of conjunction and disjunction, it's easiest to take a different approach.

If you specify multiple conditions under the same ACL identifier, the ACL evaluates as true if any of the conditions match. For example:

```
acl url_matches  path_beg /api/
acl url_matches  path_beg /opt-in/
use_backend ... if url_matches
```

Since you're using the same condition (the `url_matches` part), you can also specify multiple comparison targets on a single line. For example:

```
acl url_matches path_beg /api/ /opt-in/
use_backend ... if url_matches
```

So putting it together, picking the latter of the above 2 solutions, you can do:

```
acl prod hdr_beg(host) -i mysite.com
acl url_matches path_beg /api/ /opt-in/
use_backend prod-api-backend if prod url_matches
```